# Cannot connect through wireless interface on a server?

Tags: server, wireless, networking, ath5k

`lshw -C network` shows

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:1f:3a:01:c7:6a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=2.6.35-22-server firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:19 memory:f6000000-f600ffff
```

Comment: Please outline the steps you follow to connect.

Comment: @Evgeny, thanks for offering but I found by manually setting the MTU, I could get it to work! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this 20 minutes later. I had done a lot to try to get networking working. I was just about to delete a line in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf` when I decided to give nm-applet one last shot and after filling out the SSID and other information for my network for the two-dozenth time, I just decided to manually set the MTU value.

After applying, I finally got the coveted ¨Connect¨ dialog! I had been reading about this mythical beast all evening.

So if anybody looks in here, sometimes with an Atheros 5K, you have to manually set the MTU.